# Assigning names to a dataframe via a loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, variable-assignment

There appear to be some similar questions but I cannot quite get my head round them at this late hour

I am trying to manipulate a set of dataframes based on sql calls - something like this

```
x <- c(3,9,12) # x is of variable length in real world

for (i in 1:length(x)) {
nam <- paste("df",i, sep="")
assign(nam) <- sqlQuery(channel,paste(
"Select myCol from myTable where myVal =",x[i],sep=""));
}
```

So I am after dataframes df1,df2,df3 which I can then combine etc.

Andrie's answer below is perfect but I am having trouble extending it to two variables

```
myQuery <- function(t,x){
  sqlQuery(channel,paste("Select myCol from myTable where myTextVal='",t,"' and myVal =", x, sep=""))
}

x <- c(3,9,12) 
t <-c("00","10","12")
myData <- lapply(c(t,x), myQuery)
```

I am getting an 'Error in paste... argument "x" is missing, with no default'

I'm not sure if it is because there is a mix of numeric and character variables in lapply vector
but applying as.numeric /as.character in the sql statement did not seem to help

Comment: I know it's late hour, so probably as you felt in a micro-sleep you accidentaly pushed ENTER before writing the actual question .... :-)

Comment: The question most likely related to the fact that `assign(nam) <- ` probably isn't going to do what the OP wanted. I think you need to put that all inside the `assign` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R idiom would be to use an `apply` type function instead of a loop.  The effect of this is that your resultant data object is a `list`.  In this case it will be a list of `data.frame` objects.

Something like the following:

```
myQuery <- function(x){
  sqlQuery(channel,paste("Select myCol from myTable where myVal =", x, sep=""))
}

x <- c(3,9,12) 
t <- c("00","10","12")

myData <- lapply(c(t, x), myQuery)
```

You can then extract the individual data.frames with list subsetting:

```
myData[[1]]
```

---

EDIT.  The point is that `lapply` will take a single vector as input.  Your instruction `c(t, x)` combines its input into a single vector.  Thus you shouldn't change `myQuery` - it still only takes a single input argument.

Comment: Thanks this works fine. I am having a problem extending it to my real-world situation where I have 2 variables, where one is a character

Comment: @pssguy Well, good luck with that.  Since you give no information about the problem, there doesn't seem to be much I can do to help.

Comment: Sorry pressed entry button before I finished I will edit the original question

Comment: Thanks for answering original question. I went the mapply route for my needs

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `assign` function needs both the name and the value as arguments:

```
assign(nam, sqlQuery(channel,paste("Select myCol from myTable where myVal =",x[i],sep="")))
```

Type `?assign` to learn more...

Answer (score 1):

You need `mapply`:

```
myData <- mapply(myQuery, t, x, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

But I think better solution is to first prepare queries:

```
queries <- sprintf(
    "Select myCol from myTable where myTextVal='%s' and myVal=%i",
    t, x) # here I assume that x is integer, see ?sprintf for other formats
queries
[1] "Select myCol from myTable where myTextVal='00' and myVal=3" 
[2] "Select myCol from myTable where myTextVal='10' and myVal=9" 
[3] "Select myCol from myTable where myTextVal='12' and myVal=12"
```

And then `lapply` over them:

```
myData <- lapply(queries, function(sql) sqlQuery(channel, sql))
# could be simplified to:
myData <- lapply(queries, sqlQuery, channel=channel)
```

Comment: Thanks marek +1. The mapply solution works fine. I'll also consider your alternative. Why do you think this is better?

Comment: @pssguy Queries can be verified before sending them to server. Separation of two task: preparation queries and get the data, if all is done in the same time the chances of overall failure increase. It also make your code more readable.